# WPF - DataGrid - Dynamically added controls disappear when clicking anywhere else

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to add controls to a `<StackPanel>` in a `<DataGrid>` using the `LoadingRowDetails` event. But whenever I click outside the control it disappears.

[image]

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    SelectionUnit="Cell"
    LoadingRowDetails="manualGrid_LoadingRowDetails"
    RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
    x:Name="manualGrid"
            >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Height="80" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Checkbox" Width="225">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Test" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" Width="1">
                <StackPanel x:Name="spTest1" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}

private void manualGrid_LoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)manualGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(e.Row.GetIndex());

        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(2);
        StackPanel stackValue = GetVisualChild<StackPanel>(cell);
        CheckBox ChkBox = new CheckBox();
        ChkBox.IsChecked = true;
        ChkBox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 7, 0, 0);
        if (stackValue.Children.Count == 1)
            stackValue.Children.Add(ChkBox);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}

public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

What am I missing here?

*Note: I'm just learning WPF controls from [WPF Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) and got the sample code from there and modified it a bit*

As the current code, you can see it [here](https://github.com/vivek201/datagrid-sample)

Comment: Where is the CheckBox for the top 2 rows? Your issue cannot be reproduced based on the information you have provided. Please provide a MCVE of your issue when asking a question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mm8 I already clicked on those and they disappeared. And I couldn't upload a zip of the solution, so I just added in the main code files.

Comment: Where is your view model class?

Comment: Updated with the code

Comment: I suggest not _adding_ anything, just have the checkbox a part of the `CellTemplate` and hide/show it based on a trigger. In WPF you are encouraged to manipulate the _existing scenery_ rather than create them in code-behind. Don't worry about the invisible elements as they will not take up resources or slow down anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `CheckBox` is removed when you enter the edit mode of the cell. You can prevent this from happening by setting the `IsReadOnly` property to `true`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Checkbox" Width="225" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Note that adding controls by getting references to the visual elements that make up the DataGrid is generally a bad idea because of UI virtualization and recycling of containers.